# How do I align radio button text inn HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css

how do I align this radio button? I need the second line to stop going before the radio button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <form>
        <input type="radio" name="bunny" value="bunny"> far far away in a land called neverland there was an easter bunny who hated chocolate and loved vegetables <br>
    </form>
</html>
```

My CSS looks like this:

```
input[type="radio"] {
    text-align: justify;
}
```

http://prntscr.com/j5zzvt

Comment: a quick fix : `form{display:flex}`

Comment: Use a `label` I think that would mmake more sense

Comment: Thanks very much guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your CSS add this:

```
form {
    display: flex;
}
```

And delete this because its useless:

```
input[type="radio"] {
    text-align: justify;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much!

Comment: Glad to hear it

Answer (score -2):

You can make the label of the radio button align with first line by adding a couple of css styles to it. Try this code.

```
<form>
    <labe class="radio-option">
        <input type="radio" name="bunny" value="bunny"> <span class="label-text">far far away in a land called neverland there was an easter bunny who hated chocolate and loved vegetables</span>
    </label>
</form>

.radio-option input {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.radio-option .label-text {
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```